# replace string with string in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, replace

i'm getting error `cannot find symbol` in netbeans while using the below code for replacing the string with string.

```
public String urlEncode(String msg) {

        if (msg != null) {
           msg=msg.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        }
        return msg;
    }
```

Need help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the following code

```
private String replace(String needle, String replacement, String haystack) {
    String result = "";
    int index = haystack.indexOf(needle);
    if(index==0) {
        result = replacement+haystack.substring(needle.length());
        return replace(needle, replacement, result);
    }else if(index>0) {
        result = haystack.substring(0,index)+ replacement +haystack.substring(index+needle.length());
        return replace(needle, replacement, result);
    }else {
        return haystack;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use StringBuffer, rather than concatenate string with the plus signs. Plus signs do terrible things to memory.

Comment: @DumpHole: StringBuilder would be a better choice since no synchronization is required. Also the compiler will convert runtime-dependent concatenation to code that uses a StringBuilder. It may not always be optimal, but I think concatenation works fine in this case.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler: StringBuilder is not supported in J2ME.

Comment: I would go with the other answer, which uses StringBuffer.

Comment: @DumpHole: Wow, I feel like a goof. I think I'll ignore the java-me tag from now on... lol

Comment: but what if more than one string is present in the another string ? will it going to replace all the string using above code ?

Answer (score 7):

I have created following method for replacing String with another String.

```
private String replace( String str, String pattern, String replace ) 
{
    int s = 0;
    int e = 0;
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    while ( (e = str.indexOf( pattern, s ) ) >= 0 ) 
    {
        result.append(str.substring( s, e ) );
        result.append( replace );
        s = e+pattern.length();
    }
    result.append( str.substring( s ) );
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try an adapted version of `URLEncoder` for JavaMe published on [***code.google.com***](http://code.google.com/p/jibjib/source/browse/trunk/javame/src/com/sugree/utils/URLEncoder.java) under the project [**JibLib**](http://code.google.com/p/jibjib/) mobile client.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need for sure use your own method for handling URL encoding?
Just use URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)

```
  @param   s  String to be translated.
  @param   enc   The name of a supported
  @return  the translated String.
```

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll was introduced in Java 1.4 and I think J2ME is limited to 1.3. You must be compiling with a later JDK which is why you are getting a symbol error at runtime.

URLEncoder.encode (String s) might be your best bet. Unfortunately the URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc), as suggested by Xeon, is also a JDK1.4 API call.